# Unity VR Render Textures, Scene space rendering, and blending layers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

[using unity 2020.3]

I'm trying to slowly blend different layers in and out in VR, with both layers being visible while the fade between occurs. Right now, I am using two cameras, one as the main camera and one as a render texture (both only rendering their selective layers). Then I use UI to fade the render texture in and out. This looks and works great in 2D view (including builds), but UI components do not render in VR.

I am aware that rendering this in VR will require 4 sets of rendering (two for each eye), but I'd still like to know how to generate and display a render texture for each eye using unity.

This effect can be done in other ways and I'm open to suggestions. There are a lot of different types of elements I wish to fade in and out so I'm aware of one solution to add transparent shaders and fade particles but this can be tedious and requires a lot of setups (I'd like more of a permanent solution for any project). This being said, I'd still like to know how to manipulate what is being rendered out to the VR headset.

I'm fairly certain that the "Screen space effects" section of Unity doc Single Pass Stereo rendering (Double-Wide rendering) -- { https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SinglePassStereoRendering.html } -- is what I'm looking for, however, this still doesn't answer how to get the render texture for each eye (and I'm a little confused on how to use what they have written).

I'm happy to elaborate more and test some things out! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just to be sure the UI was just a workaround/attempt right? In the end you are speaking of actually any layer right?

Comment: Soudns basically like some post-processing which could be done using [`Graphics.Blit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.Blit.html) where one Camera can render to a `RenderTexture`, you use that `RenderTexture` in the `material` and then when your other camera renders you overlay it using the materials alpha value.